# Why is equality attribute of a class calling itself over and over?

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, attributes

I'm using MIT OCW and just learned about classes. So when equality method is called on a pair of instances, my code (edited from the original) is calling itself over and over again. The code is as follows:

```
class Animal(object):
def __init__(self, age):
    self.age = age
    self.name = None
def __str__(self):
    return "animal:"+str(self.name)+":"+str(self.age)


class Rabbit(Animal):
    tag = 1
    def __init__(self, age, parent1=None, parent2=None):
        Animal.__init__(self, age)
        self.parent1 = parent1
        self.parent2 = parent2
        self.rid = Rabbit.tag
        Rabbit.tag += 1
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print('entering equality')
        print(self.parent1)
        print(self.parent2)
        parents_same = self.parent1== other.parent1 and self.parent2== other.parent2
        print('1st comp')
        parents_opposite = self.parent2 == other.parent1 and self.parent1== other.parent2
        print('2nd comp')
        return parents_same or parents_opposite

a=Rabbit(6)
b=Rabbit(7)
c=Rabbit(5,a,b)
d=Rabbit(3,a,b)
e=Rabbit(2,c,d)
f=Rabbit(1,c,d)

print(e==f)
```

When this code is run, it is seen that Python enters equality loop multiple times.
Below is the original **eq** attribute:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    parents_same = self.parent1.rid == other.parent1.rid \
    and self.parent2.rid == other.parent2.rid
    parents_opposite = self.parent2.rid == other.parent1.rid \
    and self.parent1.rid == other.parent2.rid
    return parents_same or parents_opposite
```

The code runs just fine with the original equality attribute.
Can anyone explain me why this is happening. Thank You.

Comment: The value of the `parent1` and `parent2` attributes are *also* instances of `Rabbit`, so `==` uses `Rabbit.__eq__`. Eventually, such a call gets `None` as both arguments and returns a value without another call to `Rabbit.__eq__`.

Comment: Each `eq` call entails up to 3 `==` comparisons on other rabbit objects (assuming that a rabbit can't have a repeated parent). And each of those entails up to 3 `==` comparisons on other rabbit objects. And so on.

Comment: I think what you're _really_ asking is, "is there some way I can check the referential identity of the parent objects without invoking their `__eq__` behavior, and without needing to check their rid?". Assuming each Rabbit's rid is globally unique, then you've basically reinvented `id()` -- you could just be doing `self.parent1 is self.parent2` instead.

Comment: That said, why are two rabbits considered equal if they have the same parents?

Comment: That is the way equality was defined in that particular example. Equal parentage maybe. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are checking multiple rabbits for equality! The parents of `e, f` objects are rabbits too, and each of them has rabbits for parents. So, each equality check will call `Rabbit.__eq__` recursively, until you get to `a` and `b`

Comment: Thank you. Can't upvote your answer because I'm still new so don't have that privilege.